# Cracks in Cement Floor of Shed

Tags: crack, cement, cracks

My house has an attached garage similar to this:
[image]

The garage has rooms above it, not sure if that's worth mentioning but I'll note it. Out the back of the garage where the house would normally end, it extends out into a shed.

From a side view of the house it looks something like this:
[image]

The garage and shed have different cement floors (slabs? not sure if I'm using the right terminology there), there's a clear separation of them and they're different colors; for example, the garage is darker grey than the shed's floor.

Anyways, today I noticed for the first time (doesn't mean they haven't been there for awhile) some cracks in the floor of the shed:

[image]
[image]

The only other characteristics of cracks that I have is that they're fairly shallow.

Reading online, some cracks are OK, some cracks are warnings, cement cracking is inevitable, etc. Are these something I should be worried about?

Comment: Does not look too concerning but hard to tell from those pictures. If you don't see things like a difference in slope on either side of the crack or other signs of movement, I doubt it's a problem to worry about. I'd guess a combination of possible/typical factors such as lack of reinforcement and not cutting control joints (control joints provide a defined location for non-worrisome cracks to form.)

Comment: Is this a long single crack near the middle of the slab.? If so, take a level, or flat plate, laying across the crack at several locations, and see whether there is a ridge formed along the crack. A ridge along a wide shallow crack can be an indication of uneven settlement of the slab.